# Sorting QuerySet by a key of a JSONField is super slow

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Let's say my model is:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
     code = CharField(...)
     dynamic_columns = JSONField(null=False, default=dict, encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

This :

```
MyModel.objects.all().order_by("dynamic_columns__some_key")
```

goes a loooot slower than

```
MyModel.objects.all().order_by("code")
```

I know it's not a surprising result, however are there tricks to optimize the first operation ?

Like would defining the schema of *dynamic_columns* somehow help ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Sometimes denormalisation is your friend ;)

Comment: If you will be doing sorting operation of the `dynamic_columns`, it's better to define them in a table. You already know which columns you want to sort by (`MyModel.objects.all().order_by("dynamic_columns__some_key")`
), so it should be okay to define them in your mode

Comment: @evanstjabadi so do you suggest I add a "some_key" column in MyModel ? Not  possible in my case (multi-tenant service)

Comment: Hmmm, I am not sure how it's not possible. You already know that you expect "some_key" to be part of the dynamic_columns (because you want to sort by it). Therefore, when you get data to create an object of MyModel, you can just extract that key from the dynamic_columns and store it in your MyModel. Alternative is to create a model for the keys you know about from DynamicColumns